# iOS) Facebook - like Photo(image) viewer

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I could find 'MHFacebookImageViewer' : (https://github.com/michaelhenry/MHFacebookImageViewer)

But the README.md at there said 'Current version can run from iOS 5 to iOS 7 (But must be build < XCode 4.6.x)' at the section of Requirements.

There are also several project for this photo viewer but I think these are awkward and shoddy to apply to real service.

Thesedays, what developer use to realize facebook-like photo viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create it own your own. 
When the image is tapped , 
get backup of the current frame of image ,
then show animation to change its frame to fullscreen .
 Once it reached fullscreen you can just show a new view with the full screen image , so that you can easily handle the pinch zoom gestures. 
do the reverse animation to the backup frame of image when the full screen is closed.